# JQuery Multiple ids to hide 1 div

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a personal project just having some trouble with it.

I am trying to make a simple hover menu.

the idea is when a user hovers over a list element it shows a div and when they mouseout on the div or the element that was initially hovered on the div disappears.

for example.

When you hover on one of these a div appears.

```
<ul>
<li>Link 1</li>
<li>Link 2</li>
</ul>

<div id="link1div"><div id="link1innercontent"></div></div>
<div id="link2div"></div>
```

Now when you hover over the li the div appears and when you mouseout on the div the div disappears.

What I am trying to do is when you mouse out with either the li or div the div disappears. I am having trouble because when I try to do it both divs disappear.

My code below:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
                        <li id="link_1">Link 1</li>
                        <li id="link_2">Link 2</li>
                    </ul>
</div>

 <div id="link_1"><div id="link1innercontent"></div></div>
    <div id="link_2"></div>

$("#menu li").hover(function(){
var name1 = $(this).attr('id'); //ignore these, they are for selecting appropriate ids
var name = name1.split('_'); //ignore these, they are for selecting appropriate ids
openMenu(name[1]);
$("#m_"+name[1]).mouseleave(function(){ // I have tried $("#m_"+name[1]+",#"+name1) but it 
closeMenu(name[1]);                     // hides the div before you can access it.
});
});


function openMenu(name){
$("#m_"+name).slideDown();  
}

function closeMenu(name){
$("#m_"+name).slideUp();    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use one ID for two elements, you should use class instead:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="link_1">Link 1</li>
<li class="link_2">Link 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="link_1"><div id="link1innercontent"></div></div>
<div class="link_2"></div>

$("#menu li").hover(function(){
  var name1 = $(this).attr('class'); 
  var name = name1.split('_'); //ignore these, they are for selecting appropriate ids
  $('div.' + name[1]).slideDown() 
  }, function() {
    $('div.' + name[1]).slideup()
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange JavaScript you have here. :) Here's what I think: you want `div` to disapper when mouse leaves `div` OR `li`? So since you cannot be over both at the same time (passing mouse from one to another will trigger `mouseleave` event), here's what you have to do:

Set timeout variable `var t = setTimeout(...)` when mouse leaves `div` OR `li` (for example with 500 millis). After this time hide the div (do this in `setTimeout` handler).

Now, when you move mouse over `div` OR `li` clear this timeout: `clearTimeout(t);`. I think that's the way most people do this (is there any other?).

Comment: thanks for your reply freakish, I understand what your saying but my problem is mainly with switching between the menu links. Since mouseleave works when I enter and leave the div its just that when switching between different menu options what happens is the previous div doesn't disappear because the mouseleave is on the div not the li and I haven't entered the div for the mouseleave event to trigger, But if I put a mouseleave or mouseout on the li the div will disappear when I mouseout of the li.